# Word: Wildcard find/replace paragraph marks fails using text file

Tags: microsoft-word, cmd.exe, find-and-replace

Using Word 2013 in Win10.

I created a text file of a directory structure using CMD's DIR command piped into a text file.

I opened the text file directly in Word. I tried using Word File | Open and right-clicking in Windows File Explorer.

Word asked about the encoding, and I tried Windows, MS-DOS, US-ASCII, and Unicode (UTF-7 and UTF-8).  I had the same problem with all of them.

I want to use a wildcard search to find text that has a paragraph mark before it and **two** paragraph marks after it.

Either of these search strings in the Find box works, but they only include **one** paragraph mark:

```
^13*^13
^13(*)^13
```

None of the following works. Each one finds nothing

```
^13*^13^13
^13(*)^13^13
^13*^13{2}
^13(*)^13{2}
```

**However**, when I copy the text and paste it into a new Word document (Paste | Keep Text Only), the wildcard find with two paragraph marks at the end works as expected. All of the four listed strings produce the same results.

**Question:** Why does Word not recognize two successive paragraph marks when it opens a "DOS" text file directly but recognizes them when the text is pasted into a new Word document?

Comment: Files created from a command shell are encode as ANSI and the line ending is <cr><lf> (^13 followed by ^10).

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, at least not exactly. If I create a Word document from scratch and type into it (no pasting, no importing), a wildcard search for ^13^10 finds the paragraph marks. If a paragraph mark were strictly ^13, I would expect this search to fail. Searching for ^13 alone also finds the paragraph marks. Doing a replace with either string replaces the paragraph marks. Also, searching for ^10 by itself finds nothing. So there seems to be something illogical going on with the wildcard search. Or I'm still missing something.

Comment: Additional information, probably not important: ^11 finds manual line breaks. ASCII 11 is "vertical tab," which is an interesting choice. I would have expected ^10 (line feed).

Comment: We can reasonably make the assumption that Word is using a different internal representation when it opens the text file. But you never really get to see what that is - the best you can do is examine the XML representation. In fact, it is mostly the same, but if I select the paragraph mark of one of the empty paragraphs the XML contains a run <w:r></w:r>with a single <w:cr\> element. If I do the same for an empty paragraph typed in a new Word document I just get a paragraph with paragraph and run properties, but no run.

Comment: Whether that is deliberate, e.g. an attempt to preserve some aspect of the Plain Text file for when you save, or basically the result of a coding error, I cannot tell. But what it means is that to find a ^13^13 you actually have to find ^13x^13, where x corresponds to a <w:cr/> character. And probably nothing does. You can find the sequence using ^13?^13 but of course that is also going to find paragraphs with a single character in.